# Smoothly converting a static website to Django

Tags: django, apache2, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I currently have a simple apache `/var/www` setup. I have a bunch of static HTML files in a directory (let's call it `/var/www/mydir`), which show up on `http://mysite.com/mydir/filename.htm`.

Now, I want to start serving Django content (via a virtualenv) on `http://mysite.com/`, however I would like `http://mysite.com/mydir/` to keep serving the static HTML it used to.

Is there any way I can configure Apache to call Django in the case of `http://mysite.com/*` links and pull up static HTML in the case of `http://mysite.com/mydir/*` links?

If not, how can I tell Django to serve HTML files from `/var/www/mydir` for `http://mysite.com/mydir/* links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need Django at all to serve static content. The framework won't even do it when not running in DEBUG = True, for performance reasons.

You only have to configure Apache to have an [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) from `/mydir` URLs to `/var/www/mydir`.

Comment: With a virtualenv setup, there's no connection to Apache AFAICT. Django seems to just listen on port 80 (so there may be conflicts if I keep Apache on). Is there any way to tell Django and Apache to work together?

Comment: manage.py runserver, which listens on a port of its own, is only used for development. When moving to a 'real' webserver, communication between Apache and Django is done via an interface style known as WSGI. There is a lot to be said about that subject, but if you Google for 'Django mod_wsgi' you'll be able to find the essentials.

Comment: The Alias directive for the sub URL takes precedence over the WSGIScriptAlias for the root URL. So defining the Alias works fine. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Hosting_Of_Static_Files

Comment: A further way is to setup Apache to only send requests through to the WSGI application under mod_wsgi when it doesn't find a static file match in DocumentRoot. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive